# Remove HTTPS from a specific folder on site

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

my client asked me if I could remove and force "http" on a specific folder on the site, that is linked with another web app on another server. We added a SSL certificate lately, and it seems to be causing issues with all the links that were once made with that folder.

So right now, the whole site is in HTTPS mode. But there's 1 folder in the entire site that must be "HTTP". The rest of the entire site should remain HTTPS.

The folder is called "mailing".

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mailing
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But it's not doing anything.

There's this code block at the top of the HTACCESS file too:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.MYWEBSITE.ca/$1 [R,L]
```

I tried commenting out this part, and only putting the first block of code up there, but still, nothing.
And yes, I cleared the cache and restarted browser to test.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these 2 rules **at top of your .htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine On

$ for http except mailing force https://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+mailing[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

$ for https mailing force http://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+mailing[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Should I remove the 2nd code block that I have posted in my first post? The one that says "(?:\ Comodo...)"

Comment: I updated my answer, now you can completely comment out your 2nd rule block.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot! :)